# which file to does blue pill expect in -a flag?

Tags: ios, xcode8, linkedin-api, bluepill

I am trying to run xcui tests om multiple simulator using blue pill tool by linked in.

when I run the command: ./bluepill
output:
bluepill: invalid configuration
    Missing required option: -a/--app - The path to the host application to execute (your .app)
    Missing required option: -s/--scheme-path - The scheme to run tests.

now, the path to the host application is what i cant find in my ios project.

Inside xcode, uder products directory, I see one abc.app. On selecting see on finder, it shows a location in Library forlder which is not the same as my project.

It will be great if someone can help me out with the .app file.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the .app file which was in derived data folder. I changed the target path to the project itself which made .app file inside "build" folder.